# Efficiently "Wrapping" Constant Strings in C

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a parser in C, and one of the things that I needed when designing it was a mutable string "class" (a set of functions that operate on opaque structs representing instances), which I called `my_string`. Instances of the string class are little more than structs that wrap a `char *`, along with some metadata.

A problem arises, though, with constant strings. For example, I have several methods that return `my_string *` pointers, but sometimes I want to return a constant string. Consider this contrived pseudo-code:

```
my_string *element_get_data(my_element *el)
{
    if (element_has_character_data(el))
        return element_get_character_data(el); /* returns a (my_string *) */
    else
        return my_string_constant("#data");    /* ditto */
}
```

… where in some cases I want to fetch a pre-built `my_string` instance, but in others I want to just return the string "#data" wrapped in a `my_string` struct.

The problem with this code is that it creates a new (heap-allocated) `my_string` instance every time `element_get_data(...)` is called. C constant strings have nice semantics in that they're statically allocated in the program's DATA section, so every time a constant string is encountered, the address of that string is always the same.

It therefore seems silly to have several different `my_string` instances all pointing to the exact same `char *`. What's an efficient way to deduplicate this? Should I keep a hash table of `const char * -> my_string *` mappings? Or is there a way to use similar semantics to C constant strings? On the Mac, Core Foundation manages to do this with the `CFSTR(...)` macro.

**The ideal solution to me** would be to somehow craft a macro like `my_string_constant(...)` that stores a `my_string` struct in the DATA section of the program, so it too can be constant. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: One upside to having a hash-table is that you can keep copies of a string as a single string with just a reference counter. Also, if the program you're compiling have two string literals that are the same, but in different places in the source, you still only have one entry in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was writing up this question (or rather, almost immediately after I finished), I found the answer to my question in the form of [GNUStep's implementation of Core Foundation's CFSTR() macro](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnustep-dev/2010-01/msg00054.html). My similar implementation looks like this:

```
#define MY_STR(str) ({\
    static struct { const char *buffer; my_bool shouldFree; my_bool mutable; my_bool constant; } s = {NULL, MY_FALSE, MY_FALSE, MY_TRUE};\
    s.buffer = str;\
    (my_string *)&s;\
})
```

The reason this works is because the block of code gets inlined during compile time, which means it creates a statically-allocated struct relative to the local scope. Thus, if (e.g.) a function containing `MY_STR("Hello, world!")` is called multiple times, the same statically-allocated struct will always be returned, resulting in our desired behavior.

This concept could easily be extended beyond things like strings, allowing you to easily create your own statically-allocated object types. Neat!